# How to add pull tableview up to refresh data inside the uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I know how to add pull-to-refresh into a view controller. But right now the situations is: I have a `UIView` & that contains a `UITableView` and I want to pull the table view up at the very bottom of tableview to reload it's data.

How to add pull-to-refresh inside this `UITableView`, not it's parent view's controller.

Comment: are you try to achieve it in iOS 6?

Comment: Check out this code `https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh`.

Comment: Can you use a child table view controller?

Answer (score 24):

In your ViewDidLoad add this:

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.myTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

And refresh

```
- (void)refresh:(id)sender
{
// do your refresh here and reload the tablview
}
```

Comment: Brava. We can also use some UITableViewController if it meets the need.

Comment: @vin How would you then tell the refresh action to stop? (What code would you run?)

Comment: @playbasegames you can use endrefreshing method to stop

Comment: This method wont refresh by pulling the tableView up, only by pulling it down.

Comment: I agree with Bot and rilar

Comment: @JamesHarnett you would call the endRefreshing method on the refreshControl

Answer (score 4):

it's simple: Take one `UIScrollView` and inside it take `UITableview` and put in bottom of `UITableView` and just write Scrollview delegate method

```
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark - Scroll View Delegate Method

    - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

        if (scrollView == scrollObj) {
            CGFloat scrollPosition = scrollObj.contentSize.height - scrollObj.frame.size.height - scrollObj.contentOffset.y;
            if (scrollPosition < 30)// you can set your value
            {
                if (!spinnerBottom.isAnimating) {
                    [spinnerBottom startAnimating];
                    [self YourPUllToRefreshMethod];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```